# rails_admin setting current_user in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I have a Event model:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User'
end
```

I can type in console:

```
e=Event.last
e.author
```

In rails_admin when I create a new Event I don't want to show the author_id field in the form. I want to set the author in the controller with something like this:

```
@e=Event.new(params)
@e.author_id=current_user.id
@e.save
```

Is possible to do it in rails_admin?

I have found this [document](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/How-to-set-current_user-to-the-field) in the official wiki, but i don't want to use the cancan ability and i don't want to set the author_id field with a hidden field in the form becouse is dangerous for the security, infact the POST request can be override with a custom author_id.
I want simple assign the author_id in a controller. 
Is possible?

Answer (score 6):

I didn't find clean way to do this in rails_admin. Here is an open issue: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/1855.

This could be not the best option but you may override global logic in create action. Take a look how it works: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/lib/rails_admin/config/actions/new.rb.

There is a `register_instance_option :controller` block. It means that you may pass this option through the config. More info here: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Actions.

So if you really need it you can edit `/config/initializers/rails_admin.rb`:

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|

  config.actions do
    dashboard                     # mandatory
    index                         # mandatory

    new do
      controller do
        proc do
          if request.get? # NEW

            @object = @abstract_model.new
            @authorization_adapter && @authorization_adapter.attributes_for(:new, @abstract_model).each do |name, value|
              @object.send("#{name}=", value)
            end
            if object_params = params[@abstract_model.to_param]
              @object.set_attributes(@object.attributes.merge(object_params))
            end
            respond_to do |format|
              format.html { render @action.template_name }
              format.js   { render @action.template_name, layout: false }
            end

          elsif request.post? # CREATE

            @modified_assoc = []
            @object = @abstract_model.new
            satisfy_strong_params!
            sanitize_params_for!(request.xhr? ? :modal : :create)

            @object.set_attributes(params[@abstract_model.param_key])
            @authorization_adapter && @authorization_adapter.attributes_for(:create, @abstract_model).each do |name, value|
              @object.send("#{name}=", value)
            end

            # customization
            if @object.class == Event
              # do whatever you want
            end                

            if @object.save
              @auditing_adapter && @auditing_adapter.create_object(@object, @abstract_model, _current_user)
              respond_to do |format|
                format.html { redirect_to_on_success }
                format.js   { render json: {id: @object.id.to_s, label: @model_config.with(object: @object).object_label} }
              end
            else
              handle_save_error
            end
          end       
        end
      end
    end

    export
    bulk_delete
    show
    edit
    delete
    show_in_app

  end
end
```

Comment: Good to know that this is an option, but it seems really hacky to have to override the entire default controller when all one needs is to override one action of one controller. This could definitely be implemented better in RA. Thanks for providing the info, though.

Comment: @Chrisbloom7 totally agree.

Comment: Annoyingly, this is still the best solution if you need to tweak the default CRUD actions. In my case, there are password fields available that can be empty on submission. Sending `nil`/empty string to my backend causes validation issues, since normally the param would not be sent. I have to modify this action to filter out the empty password fields.

Answer (score 0):

pereleguine literally saved my ass today with his comment from 2 years ago. Thank you, thank you.

I had to make one modification and remove satisfy_strong_params! It's again pretty hacky, but it works:

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|

config.actions do
dashboard                     # mandatory
index                         # mandatory

new do
  controller do
    proc do
      if request.get? # NEW

        @object = @abstract_model.new
        @authorization_adapter && @authorization_adapter.attributes_for(:new, @abstract_model).each do |name, value|
          @object.send("#{name}=", value)
        end
        if object_params = params[@abstract_model.to_param]
          @object.set_attributes(@object.attributes.merge(object_params))
        end
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { render @action.template_name }
          format.js   { render @action.template_name, layout: false }
        end

      elsif request.post? # CREATE

        @modified_assoc = []
        @object = @abstract_model.new
        satisfy_strong_params!
        sanitize_params_for!(request.xhr? ? :modal : :create)

        @object.set_attributes(params[@abstract_model.param_key])
        @authorization_adapter && @authorization_adapter.attributes_for(:create, @abstract_model).each do |name, value|
          @object.send("#{name}=", value)
        end

        # customization
        if @object.class == Event
          # do whatever you want
        end                

        if @object.save
          @auditing_adapter && @auditing_adapter.create_object(@object, @abstract_model, _current_user)
          respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to_on_success }
            format.js   { render json: {id: @object.id.to_s, label: @model_config.with(object: @object).object_label} }
          end
        else
          handle_save_error
        end
      end       
    end
  end
end

export
bulk_delete
show
edit
delete
show_in_app

end
```

end